# Get relevant counts for inner nested objects based on query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I'm trying to get the counts of my leads object and contacts objects based on the query

e.g below is my index

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "Affiliate",
              "participant" : "Seychelles",
              "name" : "Leroy Smith",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Mail"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Email"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "Affiliate",
              "participant" : "Marketing Info",
              "name" : "Edwin Stone",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Email"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "VIC",
              "participant" : "CAMPING WORLD - SURFSIDE",
              "name" : "Dustin Hall",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Mail"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Five9"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "Web",
              "participant" : "ROCKYFORKRANCHRESORT.COM",
              "name" : "Martin Reyes",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "Mail",
              "participant" : "Vinguage",
              "name" : "Jesse Johnson",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Email"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "VIC",
              "participant" : "JACKSONVILLE RV MEGA SHOW",
              "name" : "Patricia Schroeder MD",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Five9"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "VIC",
              "participant" : "CAMPING WORLD - SURFSIDE",
              "name" : "Steven Smith",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Five9"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "Mail",
              "participant" : "Vinguage",
              "name" : "Aaron Ferguson",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "SMS"
                },
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Five9"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "Web",
              "participant" : "WALLYWORLDRESORT.COM",
              "name" : "Faith Flores",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "3 days 4 nights Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Email"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myleads",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "10",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "leads" : [
            {
              "program" : "VIC",
              "participant" : "CAMPING WORLD - ROANOKE",
              "name" : "Dr. Heather Collins",
              "contacts" : [
                {
                  "promotion" : "21 Days Free Camping",
                  "contactType" : "Mail"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Query

```
query = {
    'size': 0,
    'aggs': {
        'leadsCount': {
            'nested': {
                'path': 'leads',
            },
            'aggs': {
                'Contacts': {
                    'nested': {
                        'path': 'leads.contacts',
                    },

                    'aggs': {
                        'FilterContacts': {
                            'filter': {
                                'bool': {
                                    'must': [
                                        {'terms': {'leads.contacts.contactType.keyword': ['Mail']}}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to query or perform aggregations in a way that my result does not contain some inner objects (contacts in my case) which does not match the query. e.g I want to get the counts of contacts where contactType = Mail.

Right now when I apply query on contactType = Mail. I get inner objects with contactType Mail as well as other contacts with diff contactType because they belong to same parent document.

Please help, I want to get the correct count of my leads and contacts. Similarly If I try to generate buckets based on this contactType=Mail query, I get other stuff too in my contactType bucket.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your query

Comment: @Val Query added. Thanks

Comment: And what results are you getting vs what you expect?

Comment: @Val In the query, you can see I want contacts with contact type Mail but in the result set I'm also getting contacts where contact type is other than Mail.